# Can not get Ubuntu 12.04 to sleep or suspend on Toshiba Satellite L35

Tags: sleep

Suspend works OK in Windows XP on this computer, but not in Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

I had your symptoms on a HP 2000 laptop, without the Windows.  In my case, it used to work before the upgrade to 12.04.

My solution:

1. Disable the Nvidia proprietary drivers.  In my case, the one with updates wouldn't load and the original was "active".  I removed it, leaving no Nvidia drivers at all.
2. Start Ubuntu in 2D mode.  I think I have tried Ubuntu, Gnome, Gnome Classic, and Gnome Classic (no effects).  One of them may also work, but I'm sure '2D' does.

That's it.  I can suspend and resume now.  Hope this helps someone.